# How do I index this postgres table to allow for efficient MIN(time) group by `id` query?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I want to get the earliest time for a given id. So for this table:

```
table
| id | time |
|----|------|
| a1 | t1   |
| a1 | t2   |
| a1 | t3   |
| a2 | t4   |
| a3 | t5   |
| a3 | t6   |
```

where for each `id`, `time` is in ascending order, I want:

```
| id | time |
|----|------|
| a1 | t1   |
| a2 | t4   |
| a3 | t5   |
```

I want to eventually run this query:

```
SELECT MIN(time) as earliestTime, table."id" FROM table
WHERE table."id" IN %s 
GROUP BY table."id";
```

where `%s` is a large array of `id`s. However `table` can be very large.

To speed things up, I tried to create indexes for this column:

```
create index stream_time on table using btree ("id" ASC, "time" ASC);
```

but I am not sure if this would be the most efficient way for my purpose. Could someone please advise me?

Comment: Your index looks completely fine to me, and I can't think of anything better to use.

Comment: You don't need to quote `id`.

Comment: The index is fine, but if %s is a substantially large array of ids, it would be better to join on a values clause containing those ids or pass in %s as an actual postgres array and do something like `JOIN unnest(%s) AS u(x) ON id = x`

Comment: Please show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of a realistic-sized query with your existing index.

Comment: ```
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=812801.67..812889.57 rows=8790 width=49) (actual time=50887.052..50901.141 rows=17413 loops=1)
   Group Key: "id"
   ->  Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..659623.78 rows=30635578 width=49) (actual time=0.131..18788.560 rows=30632802 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.250 ms
 Execution time: 50906.833 ms
```
@jjanes

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. In general, is it right to say that btree indices are preferred for multicolumnal tables, where `>=` or `<=` comparisons are common?

Comment: What version are you using?  I would have expected at least a parallel scan if you were on a recent version.  Also, that looks like the plan for  WHEREless query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no index that will speed up this query, it always requires a sequential scan.

If there are not too many groups, [there are tricks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246979/176905) to get the result faster using a recursive query.